# How to create a factor variable from values from two other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add a new categorical variable based on values from two other columns.

In the example below, I want to create the new variable "simple" using the semester and gender info.

```
 semester gender score simple 
 01       F       152    F_01
 02       M       190    M_02
```

Can I do this with dplyr?
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tidyr`, there is `unite` to concatenate columns

```
library(tidyr)
school_info %>%
        unite(simple, gender, semester, remove=FALSE)
#   simple semester gender score
#1   F_01       01      F   152
#2   M_02       02      M   190
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
school_info <- data.frame(semester=c("01","02"), gender = c("F","M"), score = c(152, 190))

school_info <- school_info %>% 
    mutate(simple = paste(gender,semester,sep = "_"))
```

You could have used `base R` without the need for external libraries:

```
school_info$simple <- paste(school_info$gender,school_info$semester,sep = "_")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!I didn't know about the paste function. Thanks for sharing!